# auctex, direct speech highlighting

Tags: auctex, highlighting

How can I achieve a proper highlighting in auctex/emacs?

I use the german guillemets (chevrons), but the highlighting is just revers as I would use the real (french) guillemets.

**He says: »**Who are you?**« I reply: »**Just a guy who wants proper highlighting.«

The bold parts are highlighted. 
For the standard syntax table I have this snippet in my ~/.emacs:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?« ")»" (standard-syntax-table)) 
(modify-syntax-entry ?» "(«" (standard-syntax-table))
```

My guess was that a hook could help:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (modify-syntax-entry ?« ")»")
    (modify-syntax-entry ?» ")«")
))
```

But it didn't. 
The usual answer to this problem is, put

```
\usepackage[german]{babel}
```

in your preamble, but of course it is there.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `.emacs`

```lisp
(add-hook 'TeX-language-de-hook
      (lambda ()
        (when (and (eq TeX-install-font-lock 'font-latex-setup)
               (featurep 'font-latex))
          (font-latex-add-quotes '("»" "«" german)))))
```

In this way, when you load `babel` package with `german` option the quotes will be correctly fontified.

If you don't want to hook this feature to `german` option of `babel` use this code instead:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "font-latex"
  '(progn
     (font-latex-add-quotes '("»" "«" german))))
```

Comment: No, unfortunately this does not work.

Comment: @permaneder which version of AUCTeX and Emacs are you using? Do you have the lines `(setq TeX-auto-save t) (setq TeX-parse-self t) (setq-default TeX-master nil)` in your `.emacs` (see the [AUCTeX manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html))?

Comment: I have the version from git and the above lines in my .emacs, yes.

Comment: Me too, same configuration, and that code works. Have you evaluated the code or restarted Emacs?

Comment: Yes. I know this problem for a looong time and never could get it
right. For years I had this workround: I created a personal textmode
with derived-mode especially to get the proper syntax highlighting for
direct speech. It worked fine -- up to now. The file ending is .nry
and I could inlude these files into a .tex file with
\include{file.nry}. But since the update to texlive 2013 (luala)tex is not so
forgiving anymore and definitively expects a .tex file, so it ridgidly
attaches .tex to my .nry file - which in deed leads to an empty pdf. - Only to show that I had a lot of restarts already...

Comment: I added an alternative solution.  Try that.  Here both solutions work flewless.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Even with if I start emacs with -q load only auctex and the mentioned hookes...

Comment: Do you experience other problems with Emacs and/or AUCTeX? I'm starting thinking there is something wrong with your configuration, but you should debug AUCTeX to be sure.

Comment: @permaneder is this code `\usepackage[german]{babel} He says: "`Who are you?"' I reply: "`Just a guy who wants proper highlighting."'.` correctly fontified in an AUCTeX buffer?

Comment: yes it is fontified correctly.

Comment: In `style/german.el` file of AUCTeX source add `(font-latex-add-quotes '("»" "«" german))` after `(font-latex-add-quotes '("\">" "\"<" german))` line. Does it fix your original problem?

Comment: I am sorry but this does not change anything.

Comment: What's the value of `font-latex-quote-list` variable in that buffer?

Answer (score 0):

I reply to the last comment with an answer, because it solved the problem.

I do not have a variable `font-latex-quote-list` but a variable `font-latex-quotes`. This variable was set to `auto`. In the menu is a option for `german` which I chose. 
Now the german quotes `»«` are fontified properly.

Comment: If `font-latex-quotes` is defined `font-latex-quote-list` should be defined as well, they're defined in the same file (`font-latex.el` of AUCTeX source), if you have one you must have the other.